# C# Web Browser Zoom (auto wrap)

Tags: c#, html, winforms, browser

Im making a program with a web browser on it. I have a drop down menu for the zoom sizes and i need the web browser to display the zoomed html file without the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the web browser when its too large. Would like to ask for help how can i wrap it like when you use the ctrl+mousewheel to zoom..

here is my code for zooming:

```
 #region XHTML Zoom

    private void cmbZoom_i_o_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cmbZoom_i_o.Text))
            {
                MyWebBrowser.Document.Body.Style = "zoom:" + cmbZoom_i_o.Text + ";";

            }

        }
        catch { }
    }

    private void cmbZoom_i_o_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cmbZoom_i_o.Text))
            {
                MyWebBrowser.Document.Body.Style = "zoom:" + cmbZoom_i_o.Text + ";";
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private void cmbZoom_i_o_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cmbZoom_i_o.Text))
                MyWebBrowser.Document.Body.Style = "zoom:" + cmbZoom_i_o.Text + ";";
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private void cmbZoom_i_o_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
    }

    #endregion
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the question properly the websites won't respond as you are expecting.

Its deciding by the css and scripts in the website. Zoom this website(stackoverflow) and see in the chrome browser.This website is not responsive so it will zoom.

see the website http://www.awwwards.com/web-design-awards/brandon-johnson. Its responsive. so it will go for auto wrap

Comment: yes you are correct. that is my question sir. any work around for this?

Comment: are you making it for all websites or for some specific tasks(targeting only one website with some script injection)?

Comment: For only a specific HTML file. using web browser item from c#.